# Oracle gives error 12154 even though I have defined path in OracleConfiguration

Tags: oracle, .net-core

According to this: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-data-access-components/18.3/odpnt/InstallCoreConfiguration.html#GUID-24C963AE-F20B-44B5-800C-594CA06BD24B

```
ODP.NET Core will look for sqlnet.ora and tnsnames.ora files in the following precedence order:
- Directory set in OracleConfiguration.TnsAdmin property
- Directory of the running ODP.NET Core assembly
- Current working directory
```

So my code:

```
OracleConfiguration.TnsAdmin = @"C:\Oracle\product\12.1.0\client_1\Network\Admin";
string connString = "yadayada"
var conn = new OracleConnection(connString);
conn.Open();
conn.Close();
```

This will give the error 12154, even though I have defined the directory where my sqlnet.ora is. If I copy and paste the sqlnet file into my application's /bin directory, it works fine, so I'm pretty sure my sqlnet file is correct.

I am also aware of this: https://community.oracle.com/thread/4345086

But the dev said I can also get it to work if I just include the System.DirectoryServices.Protocols NuGet package, which I did, but it still does not work.

How do I get this to work? I need to get Oracle to use the sqlnet file defined in the client\network\admin folder. I prefer not to have to include the sqlnet file in the /bin folder.

My tnsnames: (obviously, this isn't used...)

```
BOGUS =
  (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=NO.SUCH.HOST)(PORT=9999)))
    (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = DONT.USE.THIS.FILE))
)
```

My sqlnet:

```
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS)
NAMES.DEFAULT_DOMAIN = somewhere.mycompany.com
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH = (LDAP)
USE_DEDICATED_SERVER = OFF
SQLNET.EXPIRE_TIME = 0
```

Comment: ora-12154 is very definitive. Either your process could not find a tnsnames.ora file, or it found one and there was no entry for 'yadayada'.  Period. Full Stop.  You talk of copying sqlnet.ora, but it is tnsnames.ora, not sqlnet.ora, that resolves 'yadayda'.  Please update your question and show the contents of sqlnet.ora AND tnsnames.ora.

Comment: If you see my tnsnames, that's just bogus, nothing there. Everything is resolved from that sqlnet. I never need to copy my tnsnames.ora to my directory to work, I just need to copy the sqlnet.ora and the ldap.ora. The problem here isn't the contents of those file, it's HOW to get everything to work without me needing to COPY those sqlnet.ora and ldap.ora to my application's /bin folder. OracleConfiguration.TnsAdmin does not work, neither does the stated workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I forgot to put the configuration for the NamesDirectoryPath. So the code should look like this:

```
OracleConfiguration.TnsAdmin = @"C:\Oracle\product\12.1.0\client_1\Network\Admin";
OracleConfiguration.NamesDirectoryPath = "(tnsnames, ldap)";
string connString = "yadayada"
var conn = new OracleConnection(connString);
conn.Open();
conn.Close();
```

Works fine now, I don't need to copy things to my application's bin folder now to make it work, Oracle will know where to look to resolve whatever it need.